# Find first value of inner array based on second value

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have

```
@array = [
  ["Single - Tuesday - $13/meal", 1],
  ["Trifecta - Mon, Wed, Fri - $12/meal", 3],
  ["Quinary - Every weekday - $11/meal", 5]
]
```

If I have the second value of the inner array `1`, `3`, or `5`, what's the easiest way to pull the first value? I.e.,

```
some_method_or_whatever(1) # => "Single - Tuesday - $13/meal"
some_method_or_whatever(3) # => "Trifecta - Mon, Wed, Fri - $12/meal"
some_method_or_whatever(5) # => "Quinary - Every weekday - $11/meal"
```

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) method:

```
@array.find{|sub_array| sub_array[1] == <your value here>}.try(:first)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@array.rassoc(1).first
# => "Single - Tuesday - $13/meal"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the second values going to be unique? Why not a hash?

```
hash =
   {1 => "Single - Tuesday - $13/meal", 
   3 => "Trifecta - Mon, Wed, Fri - $12/meal", 
   5 => "Quinary - Every weekday - $11/meal"}

hash[1], hash[3] etc
```

But if it has to be what you're asking do the numbers follow the same pattern and position? i.e. 1,3,5,7,9 etc? If so `@array.flatten[value]` will work.

Otherwise `@array[@array.flatten.find_index(5)-1]`, but obv only works if value is unique.

Comment: You are missing a step: converting the given array to your hash, e.g., `hash = @array.to_h.invert`.